# How to convert date to display properly in user form?

Tags: excel, vba, date, userform, date-formatting

When entering the date in a new record, the "Date Transferred" field is formatted for mm/dd/yyyy. When the same date filed is displayed it is showing as a string, "42353", instead of "12/15/2015".

Example of Current Code =

```
Private Sub Will18_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If Will18 = vbEmptyString Then Exit Sub

    If IsDate(Will18) Then
        txtDateTxfr = Format(Will18, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    Else
        MsgBox "Please enter a valid date mm/dd/yyyy", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```

Would like dates in 3 fields to show as "Date Received", "Date Removed" and "Date Transferred" to show as "mm/dd/yyyy" not string value.

Comment: What type of controls are you using in the VBA Form?

What does the function Format return the date as?  String or Date Value?

Comment: I created a VBA form and added a Textbox control.  I then put a date in a cell and when the form loaded I used the same format function that you provided.  The correctly formatted date appeared in the Textbox control.

Comment: Function format returns string value. Thanks for helping. After 10:00 am (EDT) I will be working on this the rest of the day until it is working.

Comment: My email address is Bertb76@gmail.com. Could I send you the full code to see if you can help me identify why dates are not showing as dates but as strings? @JoshF